# How to divide or multiply between elements of a tuple in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have the next tuple as result of a sql query:

```
tuple1 = [(245, 57)]
tuple2 = [(11249, 5728)]
tuple3 = [(435, 99)]
```

and I need to divide the 57 between 245 and the same with the rest.

I can access individual elements with:

```
[x[0] for x in rows]
```

but when I do:

```
a = [x[1] for x in rows] / [x[0] for x in rows]
```

I get **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'list'**

Comment: Why didn't you do the division in the SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [x[1] for x in rows] / [x[0] for x in rows]
```

will attempt to divide a list by a list.

What you meant to do is:

```
a = [x[1] / x[0] for x in rows]
```

which is divide elements per item in list.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple names can increase readability:

```
a = [y / x for x, y in rows]
```

Comment: However, this will break if the tuple is changed to include additional elements. A dictionary is more readable and safer though for future proofing.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be

```
list(map(lambda x: x[1]/x[0] if x[0] else 0,rows))
```